# Why am I stuck on the rescue shell?

Tags: command-line, busybox

I have an older desktop computer that I hadn't used in a few years because I hadn't had a land line. Last night a booted it up and connected it to my land line and it worked great.

Before I went to bed, I set it up to upgrade from 8.4 (told you I hadn't used it in a while) to 9.1. I was going to just slowly upgrade it to the current level.

In the morning it was frozen, so I shut it down. Probably a mistake. When I tried to reboot it, it got as far as loading grub, then gave me the following message:

```
Starting up...
Mount: Mounting none on /dev failed: no such device
udevd [866]: error getting socket: invalid argument
error initializing netlink socket
udevd [866]: error initializing netlink socket

libudev: udev_monitor_new_from_netlink: error getting socket: invalid argument
segmentation fault
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
-boot args (cat/proc/cmdline)
-check root delay (did the system wait long enough?)
-check root (Did the system wait for the right device?)
-missing modules (cat/proc/modules;ls/dev)

Alert!
/dev/disk/by-uuid-6ef025a9-5a72-475-9de3-312407265847 does not exsist
dropping to a shell!

Busybox u1.13.3 (unbuntu1:1.12-1unbuntu11) built in shell(ash)

enter 'help' for a list of built in commands

(initcamfs) _
```

And then I can't do anything, including enter help. This all seems bad.

It's been a while since I've worked with Linux, so I really don't know what to do. Is my hard drive toast? Can I at least save my files? Can I fix it?

Comment: No not toast; just a disc that has the wrong ID: "/dev/disk/by-uuid-6ef025a9-5a72-475-9de3-312407265847 does not exsist" fix this from command line :) (see /etc/fstab ) (that is an incentive to google ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

I'd be looking at this post if I were you:

- [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Follow Scott's answer up to (and including) step 4 so you've mounted your install and have chrooted into it. You should be root on your actual install. That's when you need to check your `fstab`.

1. Run `sudo blkid` to get a list of the partitions. Copy the UUID for your main disk.
2. Run `sudoedit /etc/fstab` and check that the UUID for your disk is correct. We're talking about the one for `/`. If it doesn't match up, fix it.
3. Carry on with Scott's answer. This will reinstall grub.
4. Reboot.